NPM Dependency error During Flowise AI Deployment to SAP BTP Cloud Foundry
We are currently working on deploying the Flowise AI application to SAP BTP Cloud Foundry and are facing an issue during the deployment process. I’m hoping someone here can help with insights or solutions.

Use Case: We are trying to deploy the Flowise AI application to BTP Cloud Foundry.

Source Code: The source code for Flowise AI is available on our GitHub repository:        https://github.com/FlowiseAI/Flowise.git

Local Setup:
Locally, the application builds and runs fine using the following environment:

Node.js version:  18.20.3, 18.20.4, 20.15.1, 20.16.0, 22.7.0, 22.8.0
npm version: 10.7.0

We are able to build the application locally using the following command:
commands:
  - "npm install -g pnpm"
  - "pnpm install"
  - "pnpm run build"


Deployment to BTP Cloud Foundry:
We now aim to deploy this application to the BTP Cloud Foundry environment. For this, we created a deployment descriptor (mta.yaml), which looks like this:
_schema-version: "3.1"
ID: flowise
version: 0.0.1
description: Flowise HTML5 Application
parameters:
  keep-existing-routes: true
modules:
  - name: flowise
    type: html5
    path: Flowise 
    parameters:
      disk-quota: 1024M
      memory: 1024M
      buildpack: nodejs_buildpack
      stack: cflinuxfs4
      instances: 1
    build-parameters:
      builder: custom
      commands:
        - "npm install -g pnpm"
        - "pnpm install"
        - "pnpm run build"       



The .mtar file is being successfully built with the above mta.yaml file, but when we attempt to deploy the .mtar to BTP Cloud Foundry, the app staging fails with the error:

BuildPackCompileFailed
Error Details:
The root cause of the failure appears to be a dependency issue. Here is a snippet of the error captured during the deployment process:
npm ERR! Found: @mendable/firecrawl-js@0.0.28
npm ERR! node_modules/@mendable/firecrawl-js
npm ERR!   packages/components
npm ERR!     flowise-components@2.1.3
npm ERR!     node_modules/flowise-components
npm ERR!       workspace packages/components from the root project
npm ERR!   peerOptional @mendable/firecrawl-js@"*" from langchain@0.2.20
npm ERR!     langchain@"^0.2.11" from flowise-components@2.1.3
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.


Could anyone provide some pointers or steps to resolve this issue effectively? Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated!
Troubleshooting Steps Tried
Ensured all packages were installed locally without issues using pnpm.
Attempted deploying with:
npm install --legacy-peer-deps
npm install --force

However, the error persists.
Verified the compatibility of Node.js and npm versions across local and deployment environments and checked the compatible versions available in SAP BTP cloudfoundary NodejsBuildpack and version.
